# Android GPS Tracking application with online panel

Tags: android, dictionary, gps

hello i want to develop an GPS Tracking Application with an online panel.

i have been looking and learning this code found here:

```
http://code.google.com/p/open-gpstracker/source/
```

But they don't provide any online tracking information, i need to make a GPS application with admin to see online data of the track traces and record like WAY Android application.
And i don't want user to view tracking on mobile, the application only runs in background.

I just need guide, where to start and what stuffs i need to look at.

I know asking here without a source code is waste of time, still i hope you guys can provide me a startup guide to get started with my development.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have exactly what you want:
https://github.com/tananaev/traccar-client-android

The server side code:
https://github.com/tananaev/traccar
and web interface is a separate project:
https://github.com/tananaev/traccar-web

Comment: so it means that in my case its like a mobile application and then a different project for online panel system ?

Comment: it is something useful, but not exactly for android mobile devices. They have created for windows , Linux and Mac

Answer (score 0):

A good start might be checking out this example app: https://github.com/cintric/cintric-android-demo

It uses a free [Cintric](https://cintric.com/) SDK for battery efficient tracking. It also has a cool web panel which might provide good inspiration for your app.

The SDK provides callbacks for GPS updates which you can then use to send to your server, or you can let cintric manage sending the data and sync in batches via the api.